# 400 Error on API endpoint in Guzzle that works fine in Browser & Postman

Tags: laravel, http, guzzle

I am trying to access the following public API resource:

http://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_17_5.data.json?geography=1946157081,943718401...943718512,2092957698&date=latest&variable=18&measures=20599,21001,21002,21003

When I try it in the browser, it downloads as a JSON file. When I try it in Postman, it shows as text (JSON format).

When I try it in Guzzle, I get a 400 error.

```
$apiResource = "http://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_17_5.data.json?geography=1946157081,943718401...943718512,2092957698&date=latest&variable=18&measures=20599,21001,21002,21003";

try {
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', $apiResource);
} 
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

I suspect the problem is something to do with the API returning the

```
Content-Disposition attachment
```

In the header, but I don't know what the correct way for Guzzle to handle this is.

Just to be clear, I want to get the raw text output and not the file as an attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is [get the body of the response](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html#response-body) (which is put into a Stream object) and then get the contents of that response:

```
$apiResource = "http://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_17_5.data.json?geography=1946157081,943718401...943718512,2092957698&date=latest&variable=18&measures=20599,21001,21002,21003";
```

```php
try {
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', $apiResource)->getBody()->getContents();
} 
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Edit:

Exact code used for testing:

```php
Route::get('/guzzletest', function() {
    $apiResource = "http://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_17_5.data.json?geography=1946157081,943718401...943718512,2092957698&date=latest&variable=18&measures=20599,21001,21002,21003";

    try {
        // use GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET', $apiResource)->getBody()->getContents();
        dd($res);
    }
    catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but still 400 I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you sure that's all your code is doing? I tested that code and received the json body. I'll edit my post with my exact code.